# Slow updating datagrid.datacontext when scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a wpf datagrid that is displaying some data.

I have a scroll bar and when the scrollbar is scrolled I change the datacontext of the datagrid to display some other data.

This functionality is working but I have found that the scroll bar seems pretty laggy when holding down the scroll button.

After putting some time logging in it appears that the processing part ( getting the new data, setting the datacontext of the datagrid ) takes around 00:00:00.1198219, but it takes a further 00:00:00.3100004 to intercept the next scroll event.

This means its taking almost 0.5 of a second to do a scroll.

Am I just stuck with this or is there anything I can do to speed it up?

I'll post the code I think is relevant but please let me know if you need anything else.

```
private void scrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - lastScroll);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            Console.WriteLine("Got new load");
            sw.Start();
            getLoad();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Full process took " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
            lastScroll = DateTime.Now;
        }


private void getLoad()
        {
            double startRecord = scrollBar1.Value;
            DataTable dt = panelInterface.LoadDT(Convert.ToInt32(startRecord), numberOfRecordsToLoad);       
            dtgMain.DataContext = dt;    
        }
```

Comment: Why are you changing the data context while scrolling? What are you trying to achieve? What does `getLoad` actually do?

Comment: I'll try and explain as best I can. I have a client server architecture. On the server there could be a large volume of datarows. To save the client having to request and tranfer all the data back to populate the datagrid, I am requesting only the rows that will currently be shown. When the scroll bar is scrolled I select a different subset of server data to be displayed in the datagrid...... Did that make sense? I'll post the getload code

Comment: Then you might want to look at this: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344 changing the data context you are doing is probably the wrong way and I think your sluggishness is because you are forcing WPF to reevaluate everything from scratch when you change the context

Comment: Thanks, ill have a read through that and see if I can use it in my situation :)

Comment: In addition to Bea's blog, you may want to look at the ItemContainerGenerator and using it to determine what data to load.  It is at the heart of virtualized ItemsControl clasess.